# magento 2 rest api product filters

Tags: rest, api, magento2

I am working on magento 2 api. I need products based on below filters

1. store id
2. by product name search
3. shorting by name
4. category id
5. add limit

I have try with this api but no option available

index.php/rest/V1/categories/{id}/products

Please someone suggest how to archive this.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for the (GET) API `/rest/V1/products`.

1. the store ID should be automatically detected by the store, because you can pass the store code in the URL before. If you have a store with code `test`, the API will start with `GET /rest/test/V1/products/[...]`.
2. You can use the `like`condition type. Ex.: products with "sample" in their name: `?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=name
   &searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%sample%
   &searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like`
3. you are looking for the `sortOrders`. Ex.: `searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=name`. You can even add the sort direction, for example DESC, with `searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=DESC`.
4. Use the `category_id` field and the `eq` condition type. Ex.: if you want products from category 10: `searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&
   searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=10&
   searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq`
5. use `searchCriteria[pageSize]`. Ex.: 20 products starting from the 40th, equivalent in SQL to `LIMIT 20 OFFSET 40`: `&searchCriteria[pageSize]=20&searchCriteria[currentPage]=3`

Of course you can perform AND and OR operations with filters.

Comment: Hi please help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250151/what-are-the-rest-apis-for-the-magento2-modules

Answer (score -1):

```
[
    "filter_groups": [
        {
            "filters": [
                {
                    "field": "type_id",
                    "value": "simple",
                    "condition_type": "eq"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "filters": [
                {
                    "field": "category_id",
                    "value": "611",
                    "condition_type": "eq"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "page_size": 100,
    "current_page": 1,
    "sort_orders": [
        {
            "field": "name",
            "direction": "ASC"
        }
    ]
]
```